# Array values, error about field used like a type

Tags: c#, arrays, windows-phone-8

I am now for the last time make this work, I have some values that should be in an array like down below:

```
Timereports.Breaks[] breakValue = { _nestedDateStartBreak1,
                                    _nestedDateEndBreak1,
                                    _nestedDateStartBreak2,
                                    _nestedDateEndBreak2 };
```

Please correct me if I am all wrong about how it should look just have been looking at this article:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/9b9dty7d.aspx

I am getting this error:

```
'transPA.MainPage.Timereports' is a 'field' but is used like a 'type'
```

So I have been looking in the object browser and found this:

[image: What to make of this info]

What can I get out of what I am seeing here how can I make my array work. Or am I totally lost?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Updated answer after comments:

```
TimeReports.Breaks = new[] {
                            new transPA.ServiceReference.BreakDto {
                                   Started = _nestedDateStartBreak1,
                                   Ended = _nestedDateEndBreak1 
                                },
                            new transPA.ServiceReference.BreakDto {
                                   Started = _nestedDateStartBreak2,
                                   Ended = _nestedDateEndBreak2 
                                }
                     };
```

You can change that to

```
TimeReports.Breaks = new[] {
                            new BreakDto {
                                   Started = _nestedDateStartBreak1,
                                   Ended = _nestedDateEndBreak1 
                                },
                            new BreakDto {
                                   Started = _nestedDateStartBreak2,
                                   Ended = _nestedDateEndBreak2 
                                }
                     };
```

if you add a `using` statement to the beginning of your file.

```
using transPA.ServiceReference;
```

or if that using causes a conflict you can be more precise:

```
using BreakDto = transPA.ServiceReference.BreakDto;
```

Comment: I tried both and did get errors like **invalid expression term '{'** and **Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, await, and new object expressions can be used as a statement**

Comment: Doh, I missed the new array assignment statement.

Comment: I tried this:
     Timereports.Breaks = {_nestedDateStartBreak1; _nestedDateEndBreak1; _nestedDateStartBreak2; _nestedDateEndBreak2; };

Now i am getting just 3 errors: **invalid expression term**, **; expexted** and **{ expected**

Comment: No i have tried again and when using just used **new[]** i did get this error: **Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.DateTime[]' to 'transPA.ServiceReference.BreakDto[]'** and when using the **DtoBreak[]** i did get this: **The type or namespace name 'DtoBreak' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)**

Comment: @AlexanderMogren Try now, That error message you got highlighted what the actual problem was.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30893/discussion-between-alexander-mogren-and-bob-vale)

Answer (score 0):

```
Timereports.Breaks = new transPA.ServiceReference.BreakDto[] { _nestedDateStartBreak1, 
                       _nestedDateEndBreak1, 
                       _nestedDateStartBreak2,
                       _nestedDateEndBreak2 };
```

Comment: Problem is because `_nestedDateStartBreak1` etc. are dates and not `BreakDto` objects.  Found this from the comments on my answer.